# How to use the required validation in customer add form for a custom filed?

Tags: magento2.2, customer-attribute, validation

I have created a custom field in customer add form. I want that filed as required field in the customer add form but not in customer edit form. Please suggest how can I implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is required while customer add form then there will be no validation for Edit form because value is already added while adding the customer :)

Comment: So you can use data-validate attribute on the input field - 

<input data-validate='{"required":true}'name="field1" id="field1" ... />

Comment: I have created password filed, so I cannot show it filled in the edit form.

Comment: You can use beforeShowForm function of JSGrid or Hide the password field while edit, for JS and php I'm finding the solution.

Comment: You can use php server side validation for the same, it will solve your problem.